# Qt: How to correctly calculate which row has AlternateBase color?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some Item delegate and paint method inside. And I grab widgets appearance and place it to the cell. But I can't correctly calculate which row have actually AlternateBase color, and which not. Because I have hidden rows I can't just check if row even or odd.
Qt to it, how can I do it?

[image]

For now I simply check is Viewport position is even.:

```
    void CaclControlSearchItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const         QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
const QModelIndex &index) const {

    QString bgStyle = QString("QLineEdit{ background-color: %1; border: none; }")
                      .arg(( m_tableView->rowViewportPosition(index.row()) % 2 == 0) ? bgColor.name() : QColor(Qt::white).name());
```

And btw, if I hover over missplaced color the color become correct!

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code for the item delegate.

Comment: I don't know especially about Qt, but generally you have a list of items, of which you create a new list with the displayed items, and then it's a simple even/odd question

Comment: I told that I can't use Odd or Even, because some of the rows are hidden actually, but Qt respect my hidden rows and place Alternate/White colors as well. To not overcomplicate my model -> itemDelegate communication I just want to get what Qt already knows: "which row has alternate color".

Comment: @newAgeOfHelloWorld provide a [mre]

Comment: Assuming everything is set up correctly is there any reason you can't just use [`option.backgroundBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#backgroundBrush-var)?

Comment: @G.M. option.backgroundBrush is black actually, so don't work for me.

Comment: I managed to solve it. I had to check:
 if (option.features & QStyleOptionViewItem::ViewItemFeature::Alternate)

Answer (score 0):

I had to check: if (option.features & QStyleOptionViewItem::ViewItemFeature::Alternate)
 - this is the correct solution